# pdf-tools: could not determine link -lib interface

Tags: doom, pdf-tools, clang

While trying to install pdf-tools on doom emacs (28.2) on Termux android, I get this error:

```
-*- mode: compilation; default-directory: "~/.emacs.d/.local/straight/build-28.2/pdf-tools/build/server/" -*-
Comint started at Mon Feb 13 17:53:15

/data/data/com.termux/files/home/.emacs.d/.local/straight/build-28.2/pdf-tools/build/server/autobuild -i /data/data/com.termux/files/home/.emacs.d/.local/straight/build-28.2/pdf-tools/
Failed to recognize this system, trying to continue.
---------------------------
 Configuring and compiling
---------------------------
./configure -q --bindir=/data/data/com.termux/files/home/.emacs.d/.local/straight/build-28.2/pdf-tools/ && make clean && make -s
configure: error: could not determine link -lib interface
===========================
     Build failed.  ;o(
===========================
Note: maybe try the '-d' option.

Comint exited abnormally with code 1 at Mon Feb 13 17:53:24
```

The c compiler in Termux is clang. I don't know how to proceed. I tried to reinstall pdf-tools. Any guess/advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As you already have reinstalled pdf-tools (the latest release is v1.0.0 at [vedang/pdf-tools](https://github.com/vedang/pdf-tools) by the way), I'd start by reinstalling/updating some of its main dependencies: primarily the linker, since this is what your error message complains about (`pkg install -f binutils`). If that isn't enough then also the compiler (clang, and maybe you can also try gcc?), Emacs, poppler, Termux, etc.

If that doesn't help, check that the paths to them are accessible to the built script. The underlying issue might well be that [Termux is not FHS compliant](https://wiki.termux.com/wiki/Differences_from_Linux) and hence standard Linux packages need extra configuration to find things (some hints are given in the link).

Next, as your output indicated, the first message comes from [here](https://github.com/vedang/pdf-tools/blob/b8079e4ebc2936f9772657332d50936350a65825/server/autobuild#L543) in the autobuild script and means there is no automatic handler for your OS. You might want to look at the handlers defined in that script for other OSs to find some hints of what to do.

Finally, I'd also suggest opening an issue at https://github.com/vedang/pdf-tools where you might be more likely to find help. Normally it would also help to check for related existing issues there, but for this issue the best I can find is [Linker error when compiling](https://github.com/vedang/pdf-tools/issues/42).

And don't forget to share your insights once you find a solution!